# Is it possible to efficiently change table and column names, using prisma?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I want to use prisma on an existing database. Now that I'm researching it, I realise that all my tables and columns are incorrectly named. I would like to correct the names, but I don't want to lose my data.

I did a prisma "pull" so I have a schema of my current database. But then I don't quite understand how (if possible) do I rename my tables and columns using the schema.

What are my options? Can I change the schema.prisma and make prisma take care of all the "alter" statements? How do I do this?

Comment: I don't know prisma, but in "plain SQL", you can do a simple `alter table ... rename to ...` or `alter table ... rename column ... to ...` See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) for details.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but the question was regarding prisma specifically. The idea was that I shouldn't have to write these "alter table" statements manually, prisma would take care of it. But it seems I do have to write them manually after all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not natively supported yet. There is a [Feature Request](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7790) to handle renames effectively.

You can use this technique to rename your tables and fields without dropping the data.

1. Create an empty migration file with `prisma migrate dev --create-only`
2. Add sql: ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS "OldName" RENAME TO "NewName";
3. Change table name in `schema.prisma` file
4. Run `prisma migrate dev`

Comment: Do i need additional commands for index? e.g. `@unique`

Comment: Thank you, still needed in late 2023. Though i needed 'yarn' before the command.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for changing column names (I haven't tried it with table names yet) is the following:

1. Change the column name in SQL
2. Now change the column name in your schema.prisma to the same name you changed it in SQL
3. Run npx prisma db pull

Once the 3rd step runs successfully, your column name has been changed in prisma.